# When Jenkins job in running IP gets frozen and inaccessible

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2

I have set up some python script in Jenkins with AWS/Ubuntu server.

However, when I run a job, my ip address get inaccessible http://3.82.243.44:8080/, just spinning, and I can't do anything within Jenkins app

[image]

My AWS instance is showing as Running so I don't its an issue there.

This is what I latest installed on it

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

And this is what I'm trying to build (customer python build) in Jenkins

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
sbase install chromedriver latest
pytest --headless
```

If anyone has experience and what I may be doing wrong, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have likely run out of memory, because you are executing a Selenium job on Jenkins running on a t2.micro EC2 instance. To fix this, you can change your instance type on the AWS EC2 console as follows:

1. Stop the EC2 instance from the AWS console (Instance state => Stop Instance).
2. Change the instance type to one with more resources (Actions => Instance settings => Change instance type => t2.large).
3. Start instance (Instance state => Start instance).
4. Run the job again.

Note: You will be assigned a new public IP address when you do this, so you will have to edit your DNS records. Also note that t2.large EC2 instances cost more than t2.micros.

Answer (score 0):

It's happening the same to me. The only solution I have found for the moment is to stop de instance from the AWS console and start it again. I'm sill looking for a good solution for this problem, but i'm new in this "world".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).